# Angular 6 service data doesn't populate ngx chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I'm pulling data from an Angular service and trying to populate and ngx bar chart.

```
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[];

  single: any = [
    {
      "name": [],
      "value": []
    }      
  ];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options for the chart
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  .......
```

I'm looping through the data to get individual results and then passing them to chart.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.getCustomers();
this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(res => res.forEach((item, i , res) => {this.single.push({name:(item.firstname), value: (item.age) }) }));
this.single = [...this.single];
console.log(this.single),
(err) => {console.log(err)};
}
```

I can see the data in the console, but it doesn't populate the chart. I've also noticed my first object is empty and the next ones have populated.

[image]

Could this be why the chart isn't populating with data? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be the chart has initialized before the data received from API

Answer (score 1):

This is similar problem what i faced,

The solution would bee to manually refresh as follows,

declare a variable _chart as follows,

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) private _chart;
```

you can refresh by using the following function,

```
 forceChartRefresh() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._chart.refresh();
    }, 10);
  }
```

and call after updating your data,

```
 this.forceChartRefresh();
```

Comment: No. That didn't work. But thank you for the suggestion. I think it really has to do with the first object being zero. I need to figure out how to make the first object in the array start with 0 instead of 1. Do you have any ideas?